# app.config.globalProperties - Cannot read property 'globalProperties' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to register global filter in `Vue3` but it raises this error:

```
main.js?56d7:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'globalProperties' of undefined
```

According to the [Use filter in Vue3 but can't read globalProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455290/use-filter-in-vue3-but-cant-read-globalproperties) it should work.

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import "./assets/tailwind.css";
import axiosSetUp from "@/auth/axiosSetUp";
import {formatIsoDateTime as utils_formatIsoDateTime} from "@/utils";

axiosSetUp()
const app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");


app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
    formatIsoDateTime(isoString) {
        return utils_formatIsoDateTime(isoString)
    }
}
```

Do you know where the problem is?

Comment: I was just answering the Docker question! Essentially, you have a SQL injection situation because `(`, `!` and `)` have special meaning in an ODBC connection string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh, thank you. I used the SQLAlchemy and it worked so I've deleted it and I can't find the URL so I can't undelete it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should separate the root instance from the root component :

```
const app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router);

//use the root instance to add your config
app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
    formatIsoDateTime(isoString) {
        return utils_formatIsoDateTime(isoString)
    }
}
// then you could mount it 
app.mount("#app")
```