# How can i define a global variable with Laravel 8, Inertia.js and Vue3?

Tags: global-variables, laravel-8, vuejs3, inertiajs

I want to define a global variable or provide/inject or another way in default app.js file.

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import { InertiaProgress } from "@inertiajs/progress";
import Toast from "vue-toastification";
import "vue-toastification/dist/index.css";
import { useToast } from "vue-toastification";

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]?.innerText || "Laravel";
const toast = useToast();

createInertiaApp({
  title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
  resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
  setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
    return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
      .use(Toast)
      .use(plugin)
      .mixin({ methods: { route } })
      .mount(el);
  },
});
```

I want to pass `toast` variable to all other components.

Here are some things I've tried so far:

1. Vue3 Global Properties

```
createInertiaApp({
  title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
  resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
  setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
    app.config.globalProperties.$toast = toast; // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'globalProperties')

    return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
      .use(Toast)
      .use(plugin)
      .mixin({ methods: { route } })
      .mount(el);
  },
});
```

2. Also tried Provide/Inject in AppLayout.vue

```
  setup() {
    const toast = useToast();

    return { toast };
  },

  provide: {
    toast: this.toast,
  },
```

In one of the child components i tried to inject this.

`inject: ["toast"]`

i got the error 'injection "toast" not found.'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

related to this answer ([Use filter in Vue3 but can't read globalProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455290/use-filter-in-vue3-but-cant-read-globalproperties)) The config field belongs to the **root instance** not to the **root component**. The `Vue.createApp(app)` return the **root instance** and the `myApp.mount('#app')` return the **root component**. You should config your globals properties after createApp and before mount it, like this:

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import { InertiaProgress } from "@inertiajs/progress";
import Toast from "vue-toastification";
import "vue-toastification/dist/index.css";
import { useToast } from "vue-toastification";

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]?.innerText || "Laravel";
const toast = useToast();

createInertiaApp({
  title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
  resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
  setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
    const myApp = createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
      .use(Toast)
      .use(plugin)
      .mixin({ methods: { route } });

    // config global property after createApp and before mount
    myApp.config.globalProperties.$toast = toast;

    myApp.mount(el);
    return myApp;
  },
});
```

So you can use your global property inside all components:

```
mounted() {
  console.log('global toast property: ', this.$toast);
}
```

Comment: This does not work very well with Typescript? it does not know about the config type/property, and what about composition API? you don't access 'this' anymore?